# How to set SD card clock frequency between 100 kHz - 400 kHz

Tags: frequency, clock, sd

I am interfacing a 32 GB microSD card with [PIC32MX795F512L](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en545660). I am following the examples provided in [Lucio de Jasio's book](http://blog.flyingpic24.com/programming-32-bit/).

As the author has described that to set a 250 kHz, they are driving their peripheral clock frequency by 144. Which means 36 MHz when divided by 144 gives 250 kHz. But then why are they setting the `SPI1BRG = 71;`? (SPI1BRG = SPI baudrate register.)

I am using 44 MHz as a peripheral clock frequency. What value should I use?

I am really confused in setting the clock frequency for the SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably set it to 71 as the relationship between the register value and the divider value is probably divider = (BRG register value + 1)*2. In this case, (71+1)*2=144. You just need to calculate the divider value, divide by two, and subtract 1.

Comment: what is the importance of 144.? I didn't get it properly. Please point me to any document or explain more.

Comment: You said it yourself in your question...?

Comment: Thanks I got. I am using `44MHZ` that means dividing it by 176 will give `250KHZ`. So the value I have to put in register is 87 `(87+1)*2=176` Is this correct.?

Comment: Looks right to me.  It also passes the basic sanity check that since you're using a faster clock, the divider value should also be larger.

Comment: Where did you find this equation `divider = (BRG register value + 1)*2`

Comment: It was a guess. You should check the datasheet. But I have looked at a lot of datasheets, so I know in general what sort of relationships there are between register values and dividers, this one is sensible and the numbers work out correctly.